# Sequential + Parallel Execution in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

<test name="ModuleTest">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qa.testcases.AccountTest" ></class>
        <class name="com.qa.testcases.DeviceTest" ></class>
    </classes>
</test> 


 <test name="UserTest">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qa.testcases.UserTest" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>  

</suite>
```

i want to run **AccountTest** and **Device Test** in ***Sequential*** and ***ModuleTest*** and ***UserTest*** in Parallel. The **Parallel Execution** is happening but **AccountTest** and **Device Test** are not Running in ***Sequential*** , instead they start running in **Parallel**. Is there Any way to Make them Run in **Sequential ?**

I have two test classes as follows

**1.AccountTest**

```
public class AccountTest {

@BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
}

@Test(Priority=0)
public void createAccount(){
}

@Test(Priority=1)
public void editAccount(){
}

@Test(Priority=2)
public void deleteAccount(){
}


@AfterTest
    public void closeSession() {
}

}
```

**2.DeviceTest**

```
public class DeviceTest {

    @BeforeTest
        public void setUp() {
    }

    @Test(Priority=0)
    public void createDevice(){
    }

    @Test(Priority=1)
    public void editDevice(){
    }

    @Test(Priority=2)
    public void deleteDevice(){
    }


    @AfterTest
        public void closeSession() {
    }

    }
```

The Problem is First **@BeforeTest** method of AccountTest executes and Instead of going to **@Test(priority=0)** of AccountTest , the **@BeforeTest** method of DeviceTest executes. I want the Entire AccountTest class run first before going to DeviceTest

Comment: Is there any restriction that all 3 test methods should be in same class? If not, you can move UserTest to another class and change parallel value to class instead of test

Comment: AccountTest, DeviceTest, UserTest are three different classes , and i want  AccountTest and DeviceTest to be running in Sequential. Is there any Parameter we can declare at **class** tag for ***Sequential Execution***?

Comment: You will have to create two different xmls for this OR create another test class and then call the AccountTest/DeviceTest methods within this class.

Comment: @TestAutomationEngr - Let Me Try with two different xml's. Can't we Achieve it in the Same xml ?

Comment: @METIsatish which version of testNG are you using? I just tried the same suite.xml with dummy classes and it worked correctly for me. Device class method was called ONLY after completing Account class methods. I am using testng version - 6.8

Comment: @A.J : You are Right. I m using testng version 6.8 and AccountTest and DeviceTest run sequentially . I need help in Sequential Execution of One Class after the Other Class.

Comment: @A.J : I have edited my question. Suggest me the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to change the `@BeforeTest` annotation in `AccountTest` and `DeviceTest` to `@BeforeClass`

Per testng.org

@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run

@BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

Comment: @ A.J : YES. The Same behavior as Earlier. i think I should have TWO **.xml** files

Answer (score 0):

To achieve, you can try following with one xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<test name="ModuleTest" parallel="false">
<classes>
<class name="com.qa.testcases.AccountTest" ></class>
<class name="com.qa.testcases.DeviceTest" ></class>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="UserTest" parallel="false">
<classes>
<class name="com.qa.testcases.UserTest" ></class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```